# Tag dispatching/enable_if - I am confused

Tags: c++, c++14, traits, template-meta-programming

I have the following structs:

```
struct A
{
}

struct B
{
tuple<string,string>  children{{"test1","test2"}};
}
```

I would like to create a template function that will overload the << operator on every class having a member variable called children.
If possible- only on tuples named children.

When a class with a children tuple like B is met it should iterate the tuple members and call << on each of them.

Something like:

```
template<typename RECEIVERTYPE,typename SENDERTYPE>
typename std::enable_if<std::have_children_member<RECEIVER_TYPE>::value, void>::type
RECEIVERTYPE& operator<< (RECEIVERTYPE& streamReceiver, const SENDERTYPE&    streamSender)
    {
        for_each(streamSender.children, [&](const auto& child)
        {
            streamReceiver << child;
        }); 

        return streamReceiver;
    }
```

I have tried alot of examples- but I cant really get anything working in visual studio 2015.

Comment: what is `std::have_children_member`?

Comment: that is not existing- it is meant to show my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just do this to only match types with a tuple member called `children`:

```
template<typename S, typename T,
         std::size_t = std::tuple_size<decltype(T::children)>::value>
  S& operator<<(S& s, const T& t)
  { ... }
```

And might implement the body like this:

```
template<typename S, typename T, std::size_t... I>
  void
  print_tuple_like(S& s, const T& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
  {
    void* unused[] = { &(s << std::get<I>(t))... };      
  }

template<typename S, typename T,
         std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<decltype(T::children)>::value>
    S& operator<<(S& s, const T& t)
{
    print_tuple_like(s, t.children, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    return s;
}
```

Or like:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename S, typename T>
  void
  print_tuple_like(S& s, const T& t, std::false_type)
  { }

template<std::size_t N, typename S, typename T>
  void
  print_tuple_like(S& s, const T& t, std::true_type)
  {
    s << std::get<N>(t);
    print_tuple_like<N+1>(s, t, std::integral_constant<bool, (N+1 < std::tuple_size<T>::value)>{});
  }

template<typename S, typename T,
         std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<decltype(T::children)>::value>
  S& operator<<(S& s, const T& t)
{
    print_tuple_like<0>(s, t.children, std::integral_constant<bool, (N != 0)>{});
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is very clever- I did not know you could do it that way. I am having a hard time making it compile though- I must be doing something wrong, could you provide an example? Perhaps using my attempt: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64432171e853f3f8

Comment: @Hansvesselgård The way you've written `operaor<<` is wrong for both `A` and `B`. They should be non-member (possibly friend) functions. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9819019c6591d89a

Comment: Ahh, with that it compiles- but only when I use clang. When using visual studio 2015 i get:  error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't define tuple_size for this type.
 note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tuple_size<unknown-type>' being compiled
  note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void print_tuple_like<S,std::tuple<Signature::A,Signature::B>,0,1>(S &,const T &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1>)' being compiled with
 [
  S=std::ostream,
 T=std::tuple<Signature::A,Signature::B>,
 _Ty=size_t
  ]

Comment: I have a very hard time finding an example that works in visual studio 2015 :(

Comment: @Hansvesselgård, your initializer for `children` is unnecessarily complex. You don't need equals _and_ braces _and_ a function call. Just `tuple<A, B> children{A(),B()};` works fine, or since you're just default-constructing the elements anyway just `tuple<A, B> children{};`

Comment: @Hansvesselgård, maybe Visual Studio still doesn't support expression SFINAE, which is the sane way to constrain that function.

Comment: Nope, still [no expression SFINAE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/10573602.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your advices Jonathan- I have made an additional post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035563/do-visual-studio-c-compiler-or-clang-have-incorrect-behavior after i discovered it was easy to fix if I want to change Microsoft c++ files