# Does the standard require std::tuple_size to be SFINAE-friendly?

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

Edit append:
The question title was "do Visual Studio compiler or Clang have incorrect behavior"- but that have been changed.

So I add here that clang and gcc compiles it the way I intended, but VS does not.

I have the following code:

```
template<typename S, typename T, std::size_t... I>
  void
  print_tuple_like(S& s, const T& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
  {
    void* unused[] = { &(s << std::get<I>(t))... };      
  }

template<typename S, typename T,
         std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<decltype(T::children)>::value>
    S& operator<<(S& s, const T& t)
{
    print_tuple_like(s, t.children, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    return s;
}
```

and I get an compiler error:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\utility(313): error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't define tuple_size for this type.
1>  c:\users\jonas\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7.cpp(36): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tuple_size<unknown-type>' being compiled
1>  c:\users\jonas\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7.cpp(43): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void print_tuple_like<S,std::tuple<Signature::A,Signature::B>,0,1>(S &,const T &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              S=std::ostream,
1>              T=std::tuple<Signature::A,Signature::B>,
1>              _Ty=size_t
1>          ]
1>  c:\users\jonas\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7.cpp(50): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'S &operator <<<std::ostream,Signature,2>(S &,const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              S=std::ostream,
1>              T=Signature
1>          ]
```

That is because the following code in visual studio:

```
// TEMPLATE STRUCT tuple_size 
template<class _Tuple>  
struct tuple_size   {   // size of non-tuple
    static_assert(_Always_false<_Tuple>::value, "The C++ Standard doesn't define tuple_size for this type.");   
};
```

make the substitution failure into a hard failure- making the SFINAE SFIAE

If I remove

```
static_assert(_Always_false<_Tuple>::value, "The C++ Standard doesn't define tuple_size for this type.");
```

it works.

Is the code strecthing the c++ standard rules?
Or is Microsoft in the wrong?

Comment: That is some pretty intense code there. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I have a class with a member named children that is a tuple the tuple should get iterated and the children << streamed

Comment: Any suggestions for an alternative approach is also welcome :)

Comment: As a general rule, MSVC is always wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard mandates that `tuple_size` **not** be SFINAE friendly, but [this is considered by many to be a defect, and looks on-track to be fixed in C++17](https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42).

It is required that all specializations (which in standard-speak for "template instantiations") of `tuple_size` basically be `std::integral_constant<size_t, ?>` or inherit from it.  (It leaves some freedom to the compiler)

If the primary template isn't defined, then it doesn't violate that.  But if the primary template is defined to be an empty struct (or similar), then that empty struct is a template instance (which the standard calls a "specialization") that is not essentially `std::integral_constant<size_t, ?>`.

By my reading, it would be legal for the primary template (the "failure" case) to be `std::integral_constant<size_t, 42>` or any other constant.  Useless and evil, but legal.  But being an empty struct violates the standard.

However, the arguments about changing this to mandate an empty struct are about wording, and not about if it is a good idea.

Thanks to @T.C. who solved this in a comment thread on another answer here.

Answer (score 6):

N4140 20.4.1 describes `tuple_size`'s non-specialized version as:

```
template <class T> class tuple_size; // undefined
```

By providing a definition, the MSVC lib has violated the standard.

You should realize however, that your question is not about the compilers involved, but rather the standard library implementations.

Comment: can someone more familiar with the standardese meaning of "undefined" in this case confirm?

Comment: You're exactly right. "Undefined" in this case means "no definition", i.e. "no class body".

Comment: In my copy of N4140 it does not say `// undefined`, it only says that all **specializations** need to meet the `UnaryTypeTraits` requirements. Which does not make any statement about the base template.

Comment: @DanielFrey sorry, I grabbed the wrong section number, it says that it 20.4.1 (under a reference to 20.4.2.5)

Comment: Ah. Well, in that case it's "only" the synopsis, which is non-binding in this case. 17.6 only mentions some requirements for the *defined* stuff from the synopsis, but it does not mention things marked (commented) as *undefined*.

Comment: @DanielFrey "specialization" in the standardese sense can mean "instantiation" in the colloquial sense (e.g., `bitset<31>` is a "specialization" of `bitset`). Also, [res.on.headers]/p1 says that "A C++ header shall provide the *declarations* and definitions that appear in its synopsis". `template <class T> class tuple_size;` is a declaration.

Comment: @T.C. VC++ does provide the declaration and definitions, but it provides *more* definitions than listed in the synopsis.

Comment: @T.C. so, an empty `{}` primary template is in violation of the standard?  But a primary template of `tuple_size` that is `std::false_type` is not?  And a non-existent body is not?  (arguably, there are no specializations of an undefined primary template that are not template specializations?)

Comment: @Yakk `false_type` is also in violation (the `BaseCharacteristic` must be `std::integral_constant<size_t, N>`). Also, https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42

Comment: @T.C. ok ok, are you saying it would be compliant for a C++ standard library to define `tuple_size<int>` to be `std::integral_constant<size_t, 7>`.  Because 7 seems like a friendly number.  (and yes, making it `{}` and saying that all specializations should be yada yada, or the empty struct, is probably good).

Comment: @Yakk Why not 42? :) I'm not sure, really. Either the base template must be undefined - so that there's no specialization `tuple_size<int>`; or it's UB to do `tuple_size<int>`, in which case defining it as `std::integral_constant<size_t, 7>` is perfectly legal. I'm personally inclined towards the first interpretation.

Comment: @T.C.: Your terminology seems off; I do not believe "specialization" is appropriate when, say, declaring a local variable `bitset<31> local_var;`. AFAIK, specialization is when you are providing a definition of the class; i.e. `template<> struct bitset<31> { ... };`.

Comment: @Hurkyl It's the core language's terminology, not mine. [temp.spec]/p4: "An instantiated template specialization can be either implicitly instantiated (14.7.1) for a given argument list or be explicitly instantiated (14.7.2). A specialization is a class, function, or class member that is either instantiated or explicitly specialized (14.7.3)."

Comment: "You should realize however, that your question is not about the compiler's involved, but rather the standard library implementations." yes- of course I meant "the compiling system"

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this perhaps work with some modifications?

```
template<typename S, typename T,    typename   tuple_element<0,decltype(T::children)>::type >
    S& operator<<(S& s, const T& t)
```